# What does the %in% operator compares exactly in case I compare 2 data frames

Tags: r, dataframe

So I have

```
df=data.frame(age=c(10,12,12,13,13,10), name=c('Maria','anders','anders','per','johanna','Maria'))

dups=df[duplicated(df),]
```

What R does when I run `df %in% dups`

Output: `FALSE FALSE`

I do realise for example if I run `df$name %in% dups$name`

Output: `TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE`

which compares every `name` of `df` with the `name` of `dups` and checks if a `name` is found at least once on `dups`. I would assume  `df %in% dups` would check every row of `df` against every row of `dups` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Looks like the output you expect from `df %in% dups` is the output of `duplicated(df)`

Answer (score 4):

When `%in%` is applied to data frames, the comparison takes place *column-wise*.

For example

```
df %in% df["age"]
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

compares each column in `df` with the column in the one-column data frame `df["age"]`. Since the `age` column is identical in both data frames, the first value is `TRUE`.

---

For a *row-wise* comparison, you can use the following (complex) command:

```
sapply(seq(nrow(df)),
       function(i1) any(as.logical(rowSums(sapply(seq(nrow(dups)),
                                                  function(i2) df[i1, ] == dups[i2, ])))))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Got it. So if I wanted to make a comparison row by row, should I invert the data frames?